# Javascript : drag and drop image tag

Tags: javascript, html, image, drag-and-drop

I wanted to know how to do a drag and drop image tag using javascript. I know html5 each element can be dragged but I wanted to make it work on older browser. I have made the drag and drop using javascript and it worked fine except in ie and firefox when mouse down, the mouse move event didn't react unless the user click it, and that is the reaction of ie. On firefox, the image got changed to semi-transparency and draggable but my code that dragging it.

Can anyone know how to solve this problem ? please help.

Comment: what you have done so far can you just create a demo on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried jQuery yet? with the addon jQuery ui you can drag and drop every object on a website..
[jQuery UI: draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now i am able to prevent default dragging of the firefox but not the ie. I have tested on chrome and safari now firefox all working. i've bind the dragstart event and return false inside the event.