# Add images to dynamic table by dragging

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dom-events

I am fighting with this little problem for several days.

I need to select an image from the top row and add it to any chosen cell of the table. I managed to do it on click.

My problem is how to add the same image to the cells by dragging. I tried to use `onmouseover` if `onmousedown`, but it did not work at all.

I would prefer not to use jQuery.

This is a simplified version of my code with dummy images. Thanks.

```js
function fillup(img) {
  var symbol = img.src;
  var tbl = document.getElementById("New");
  for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
      tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = (function(i, j) {
        return function() {
          tbl.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = '<img src="">';
          tbl.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = '<img src=' + symbol + '>';
        };
      }(i, j));
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 180px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="symbolToolbars" id="symbolToolbars" style="display: inline-block;">
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="button">
      <img src="https://www-01.ibm.com/software/be/analytics/images/brandpages/icon-bi60x60.jpg" onclick="fillup(this)" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="button">
      <img src="http://www.citiesofthefuture.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/recycle-29227_640-60x60.png" onclick="fillup(this)" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="button">
      <img src="https://maincdn-usedsolodresses.netdna-ssl.com/images/bookmark/large/email.jpg" onclick="fillup(this)" />
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
<br />
<table border="1" width="180" height="180" id="New" style="cursor: pointer">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript : drag and drop image tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036136/javascript-drag-and-drop-image-tag)

Comment: No, I would like not to use jQuery. 
In this line when I change onclick to onmouseover, it works but I have not much control over which cells to fill up with images.

tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = (function(i, j) {  
like that
tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onmouseover = (function(i, j) {

I need to have mouse down, select a cell and draw down or aside inserting the same image while moving. As soon as I do mouse up, no more cell content should be changed.

Later, I need to select several filled with different images cells, drag down and fill some rows bellow with the same set of images.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```js
var symbol="";
function fillup(img) {
 symbol = img.src;
}

function load(){
  var tbl = document.getElementById("New");
  for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
      tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onmouseenter =  function(){
          if(symbol!=""){
   this.innerHTML = '<img src="">';
   this.innerHTML = '<img src=' + symbol + '>';
   symbol = "";
   }
  };
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 180px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="load()">
    <div class="symbolToolbars" id="symbolToolbars" style="display: inline-block;">
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="button">
          <img src="https://www-01.ibm.com/software/be/analytics/images/brandpages/icon-bi60x60.jpg" onmousedown="fillup(this)" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="button">
          <img src="http://www.citiesofthefuture.eu/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/recycle-29227_640-60x60.png" onmousedown="fillup(this)" />
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="button">
          <img src="https://maincdn-usedsolodresses.netdna-ssl.com/images/bookmark/large/email.jpg" onmousedown="fillup(this)" />
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <table border="1" width="180" height="180" id="New" style="cursor: pointer">
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

</body>
```